# Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set that uses temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to retrieve column definitions for a stored procedure using the following query:

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[foo]
    @DATABASENAME = dbname,
    @TABLENAME = tblname,
    @DATEFROM = N''20170101'',
    @DATETO = N''20170201'''
```

And I get the following response:

> Msg 11526, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
>   The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #Tables(CubeSchema,TableName,DateFilterColumn,SelectColumns) SELECT 'Col1','Col2' in procedure 'foo' uses a temp table

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Edit: I have not the rights to view and/or alter the stored procedures, so unfortunately solutions of this sort won't work.

Comment: When you just run your stored procedure is there a result set returned? Are all the columns named properly? What is your procedure doing? If it is just reading data, you might think to change this to an inline table valued function. I try to avoid SPs unless I want **to do** something...

Comment: The sp returns a result set that is always the same (not conditional) and all columns are named properly. The stored procedure is created by a client to offer me some data because I am not allowed to directly query their tables. They did not offer documentation regarding the column datatypes and I would like to have a look at them. That's the case.

Comment: [In this article there is discussed the same issue (with working sample!)](https://raresql.com/2014/01/10/sql-server-2012-fix-error-11526-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined-because-statement-ls-in-procedure-ls-uses-a-temp-table/). If you cannot change the SPs code - according to this -  there's little light...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the SP code, neither am I able to see the code. It is just provided as is, just for execution.

Answer (score 2):

Without altering your stored procedure the answer is MAYBE.

The option you are using ('`sp_describe_first_result_set`') wont work with the temp table, since you are using an `INSERT` statement.
If you would alter the `INSERT` statement to a `SELECT INTO` statement it might work for storing the data into the temp table, but you still wouldn't get your data out of it, since it isn't available. I am not sure about the internals of '`sp_describe_first_result_set`', but it looks like it is using the `SET FMTONLY ON` option, which will fail because of the temp table.

So, if you want to avoid this, alter the stored procedure to use a table variable instead of a temp table (`@table` vs `#table`).

If you are not limited to SQL Server and you can program your way around this in a programming language (for example .Net using ADO.Net), you are able to use the `GetSchemaTable` method of the `ExecuteReader` result, like this:

```
var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But what is the text of the sqlCommand? it it's steel 'sp_describe_first_result_set'?